# Eager loading for two associations of same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to eager load these associations with one query

```
class Pair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :buddy, :class_name => "User"
end


class PairsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @pair = Pair.includes(:user, :buddy).find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

the query is the following:

> Pair Load (3.1ms)  SELECT `pairs`.* FROM `pairs` WHERE `pairs`.`id` = 935029848 LIMIT 1
>
> User Load (4.3ms)  SELECT users.id FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (965902799)
>
> User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT users.id FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (274512568)

but I want to get:

> Pair Load (3.1ms)  SELECT `pairs`.* FROM `pairs` WHERE `pairs`.`id` = 935029848 LIMIT 1
>
> User Load (4.3ms)  SELECT users.id FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (965902799, 274512568)

Comment: Isn't `SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id IN (1)` and ` SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id IN (2)` same as `SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id IN (1, 2)`? Both cases will yield in users with `id` 1 & 2. I didn't get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that in rails right now, because rails by default assumes that different associations have different tables, and it can't combine includes from different associations into one query while eager loading, even if these associations have same table.

**UPDATE**: Moreover, I think it's not even feasible to do, because if you think about your data relationships: you're trying to load User and Buddy for a Pair, when you do it with 2 queries it's pretty straightforward, you know who's User and who's Buddy, but think about case when you do it with 1 query, how would you know if the retrieved record is a User or Buddy? There's no way to know that 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@pair = Pair.joins(:user, :buddy).find(params[:id])`

Comment: it returns the following query, and not eager loaded:

>  Pair Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `pairs`.* FROM `pairs` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `pairs`.`user_id` INNER JOIN `users` `buddies_pairs` ON `buddies_pairs`.`id` = `pairs`.`buddy_id`

Comment: Try to add `includes(:user, :buddy)` after joins

Comment: wow! it returns one query! but it's too long query. is there no other problem when i request many 'pairs' with _"@pairs = Pair.where(:user_id => params[:id])_"?

Comment: As I see in docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) `includes` just tries to eager load associations with another query, while `joins` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations) creates a query with joining associations by INNER JOIN. So using my example query will return only Pair records wich have corresponding records of user and buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this. You can use the :include parameter (Rails 2) or the includes method (Rails 3) respectively when doing your ActiveRecord finds.  Here's an example loading two models that are associated with a blogpost: tags and comments. Comments also has a nested commenter:

```
# Rails 2
Blogpost.all(:include => [:tags, { :comments => :commenter }])

# Rails 3
Blogpost.includes(:tags, { :comments => :commenter }).all
```